# java.lang.NullPointerException: decodeResource(context.r…rces, R.drawable.ic_logo) must not be null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap

I am trying to get album art uri from music (if null/empty, display my own in app drawable)

but I get:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: decodeResource(context.r…rces, R.drawable.ic_logo) must not be null**

**Utility.kt**

```
fun getAlbumArtBitmap(context: Context, albumId: Long): Bitmap {
    try {
        return when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P -> {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(
                    context.contentResolver,
                    getAlbumArtUri(albumId)
                )
                ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
            }
            else -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                context.contentResolver,
                getAlbumArtUri(albumId)
            )
        }
    } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
        Timber.e(e)
    } catch (e: UnsupportedOperationException) {
        Timber.e(e)
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.ic_logo)
}
```

The drawable (**R.drawable.ic_logo**) is an xml vector drawable (svg imported) and sits in drawable folder

**Player.kt**

```
 val artwork = getAlbumArtBitmap(context, song.albumId)
 putBitmap(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, artwork)
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, **R.drawable.ic_logo** is a vector image.

I ended up using this:

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_logo)?.toBitmap()
```

Converting vector drawable to bitmap, and it worked!